# Cannot create new using Identity ApplicationUserManager

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identity

In brief summary the error message I am receiving is:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name '*NowDeletedDatabase*.dbo._SharedIdentity_UserIds'.

and this is the code that throws it:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, SuperAdmin")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(Edit model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(model);
        var user = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = model.Email,
            Email = model.Email,
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName,
            PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber
        };
        var result = _userManager.Create(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _userManager.Update(user);
            await _userManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Account Details", "email body text");
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
            return View(model);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("UserList", "Account");
    }
```

when I call _userManager.Create the above error is thrown (doesn't matter if I call CreateAsync or even try and save directly to the DB using my IdentityDbContext .add() .saveChanges() methods).

I've had a look through my code and done a search on *NowDeletedDatabase* (ctrl+f Entire Solution) and there are no references to this DB in my code so I'm perplexed as to how this reference is getting called.

Additionally it is worth noting that elsewhere within this project I can Edit users that already exist and save changes by doing _userManager.Update(user); and this runs without issue.

Finally, it's worth me mentioning identity once sat in this *NowDeletedDatabase* DB before being split out into its own DB along with the project that was implemented alongside it. Code was copy pasted as I went along and I'm starting to think that may be the root cause of my problems; however it still seems madness that I can't find a reference to this old DB in my code and simply swap this out with correct details.

**Update**
Relevant sections from config files:

**Web Config**

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="sharedIdentityConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Shared_Identity;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**App config:**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>

  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

sorry about the messy formatting.

Unless I am misunderstanding these connection strings the 3 of them should all be looking at my localhost with 1 of them explicitly targeting the correct DB while the other two are just authenticated against the server. However it's my understanding that my lib class would use the connection string specified within the web.config file anyway.

**Update 2**
I've just noticed that "SharedIdentity" as part of the error "'*NowDeletedDatabase*.dbo._SharedIdentity_UserIds'" was never part of the database schema, the only relevant reference I have to "SharedIdentity" is a class within my lib project, this class inherits IdentityDbContext and I can confirm that there is no property called UserIds within this class (inherited or otherwise).

Comment: Are you sure you do not have 2 different connection string? One may be into your new database and the other to the older database? I know you did a search but maybe this one has been created in a localdb instance? From what I read, I believe that you are Updating and Creatine in two different project right?

Comment: I've had a double check of my config files and attached the relevant parts above. I'm definitely not explicitly targeting this old DB.  Also just to clarify my edit functionality is functional and within the same project in the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my SQL db had a trigger setup on the ASPNETUsers table that was calling this old DB. Thus the error.

Deleting this trigger, as it was no longer required, resolved my problem.